# Override Auto Style in Wordpress Post Image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am scratching my head for the last few days regarding wordpress auto styling in post images. Here is the html source of the image of a post-

```
    <img width="240" height="180" src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/my-first-image.jpg" class="attachment- size- wp-post-image" alt="My First Image Post" srcset="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/my-first-image.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 240px) 100vw, 240px" style="height: 107.5px;"><br><br>
```

Here how does wordpress calculate this `style="height: 107.5px;"` ?
If I want this to be `style="height: 125.5px;"` what should I do ? I have tried to override this `style="height: 107.5px;"`. But all goes in vain.

Comment: have you tried wrap that image into a div then add style to that div in css file of your theme. ps: you may try add `!important` in the width rule.

Answer (score 1):

As for why wordpress calculates and adds inline code for `style="height:107.5px"`, probably depends on your theme.

As a solution to your problem try adding this to your style.css

```
.article img {
  height:125.5px !important;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't find anything in the theme that results in such inline code. However !important works for now. Thanks.